# SharePoint CreatePage.aspx page does not redirect to pages library after page is successfully created

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, master-page, page-layout

I am facing problem while creating new page to pages library using particular page layout. When I create a new page from CreatePage.aspx page in library, it did not get redirected to newly created page or to pages library but shows CreatePage.aspx page only. I can find this newly created page is added to page library. The issue is redirection to pages library does not happen even after successful page creation.

Comment: I have same issue, but in the Farm rest of all Site Collections works perfectly, So how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue that was resolved with the [May 2015 Cumulative Update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3039780). Or, you can apply [KB3039703](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3039703) if you don't want to apply the full CU.

Comment: @Trevor, My rest of all Site collection works perfectly. So what is the issue either the above as answered or else?